# Contours all getting labeled as zero in my contour plot

Tags: plotting

As you can see from the plot below, my contour plot renders several contour lines. The legend shows the how values change with colors.

However, all the contour lines on the plot are labeled 0, which is wrong because the value is changing with color. The real 0 contour should be the middle one.

What is the problem here, and how can I correct it?

```
c = 1;
NN = 0.365*10^19;
GradN = -9.42*10^19;
Te = 143;
λDe = 7.43*1000*Sqrt[Te/NN];
λDi = 7.43*1000*Sqrt[Ti/NN];

lne = Log[4*Pi*NN*λDe^3];

lni = Log[4*Pi*NN*λDi^3];
νi = 4.8*10^(-14)*NN*lni/(Ti^1.5);
νe = 2.9*10^(-12)*NN*lne/(Te^1.5);
Me = 9.109*10^-31;
Mi = 1.672*10^-27;
e = 1.602*10^-19;

R = 1.5; (*m*)
a = 0.2; (*m*)
ϵ = a/R;
B = 1;
BT = 0.955;
BP = Sqrt[1 - BT^2];(*rw*BT/(R*qs) B=Sqrt[BT^2+BP^2]*)

Clear[r]
ι0 = 1.551;
ι1 = 0.05238;
ι2 = -0.07569;
ι3 = 0.12862;
qr = 1/(ι0 + ι1*r/a + ι2*r^2/a^2 + ι3*r^3/a^3);

m = 5;(*m,mode,number*)
n = 8;
risola = Solve[qr - m/n == 0, r, Reals];
rw = r /. risola[[1]];
dw = 0.01;(*Width of the island 1cm*)
δw = dw/R;(*Width divided by major radius R*)

Plot[1/qr, {r, 0, a}, GridLines -> {{rw}, {m/n}}];

Clear[r];
dqr = D[qr, r];
r = rw;
dqs = dqr;
qs = qr;

Clear[r];
ve = Sqrt[2*Te*e/Me];
vi = Sqrt[2*Ti*e/Mi];
νerefe = 10^-4*ve/(qs*R);
νirefe = 10^-2*vi/(qs*R);
ωbe = ve/(R*qs);
ωbi = vi/(R*qs);
νe = νe/ωbe;
νi = νi/ωbi;

drdΦ = 1/(2 Pi*BP*R)/(dqs*dw/qs);
H = Exp[-((r/a - rw/a)/dw/a)^2];
G = Exp[-((r/a - rw/a)/dw/a)^2];

xx = 100;
C1e = (Te/(B*r))^2;
C1i = (Ti/(B*r))^2;
ωE = drdΦ*Er/(B*r);

gammadwscanee = -(GradN + NN*Er/Te)*(drdΦ)^2*
   C1e*(νe*
     ve/(qs*R)/(ϵ))*(R*BP)^2*(dqs*
      dw/qs)^2*(m*δw)^2*ϵ^(0.5)/(ωE^2*(R*
          BP)^2*(dqs*dw/qs)^2*
       m^2/(0.22*G) + (νe*ve/(qs*R)/ϵ)^2/(0.5*H));
gammadwscanii = -(GradN - NN*Er/Ti)*(drdΦ)^2*
   C1i*(νi*
     vi/(qs*R)/(ϵ))*(R*BP)^2*(dqs*
      dw/qs)^2*(m*δw)^2*ϵ^(0.5)/(ωE^2*(R*
          BP)^2*(dqs*dw/qs)^2*
       m^2/(0.22*G) + (νi*vi/(qs*R)/ϵ)^2/(0.5*H));
gammadwscan = Numerator[Together[gammadwscanee - gammadwscanii /. r -> rw]]

ContourPlot[gammadwscan, {Er, -5000, 5000}, {Ti, 20, Te}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, ContourLabels -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Hard to help you out with just a picture. Where's the code that generated this?

Comment: @J.M. Just add the code. Took some time to figure out how to add code in code format.

Comment: This (Debye length in unit of meter) means multiply the symbols 'Debye' 'length' 'in' etc togther.  Comments are (* comment text *).  I don't think this is your problem but it won't help.

Comment: Additionally do you expect the result values to span the range -2x10^41 to +2x10^41?  This seems a bit wide for anything physically realizable.

Comment: This is the particle flux which could be this order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as if Mathematica's contour labeling can not handle the immense range of your plot. When the `gammadwscan` is scaled down, everything looks good.

```
ContourPlot[gammadwscan/1*^40, {Er, -5000, 5000}, {Ti, 20, Te},
  ContourLabels -> All,
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: OP could always add a label to the legend stating that the plot is in peta-yotta-particles/meter.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Stupid issue.

Comment: @yangyang. I don't think it is a stupid issue. I think you should make bug report to WRI. The above is only an explanation of what is going wrong and a work-around, not a solution.

Comment: @m_goldberg I am not sure if this is really a bug because as you could see that the difference between the lines are too small to be shown in numbers. Anyway, I don't know how to report bug, so if you want to, you could report this. :-)